# which datat type should use for exact calculation in android

Tags: android, double

Multiplication of two float numbers provide value like below 
130.82(float) X 62.0 (float) =  8110.8403  (float) instead of 8110.84 .

Also,  500001.0 (float) X 47.0 (float) = 2.3500048E7 (double) instead of 23500047

Answer (score 1):

If it is about monetary calculation then you can try to use BigDecimal, int or long.

Floats and double both cannot be used for exact calculations. Both the datatypes follow the ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) standards.

Comment: Voted up for adding reference to IEEE 754

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be so hard to figure out that all calculated values have a length of 8 unique numbers, followed by an exponential value ;)

to make sure your values will be any different from default length, you'd have to floor or max the values yourself or i.e. use round($value, $precision (length behind decimal dot)) in the example of php

Else, ofcourse, the value will retain the default length.